# Is the Hotland boat becoming a dog an undiscovered easter egg in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

So, I was going back to Snowdin to attempt to buy a spider donut (for the muffet battle) and I decided to go to Grillby's. I talked around in there, and when I went back to the boat man to go to hotland, THE BOAT WAS A DOG. Is this an undiscovered easter egg?

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, I don't think so.

[image: River person on dog boat]

From the [Undertale Wiki](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/River_Person):

"Sometimes their boat has the face of a dog and runs on top of the water. This is possibly a reference to Mother 3 when Lucas rides his Running Table."

Answer (score 0):

No, this just happens on certain travel paths.
Also, once you exit the room where Flowey talks about what you did in the Toriel fight, you cannot go back in to the ruins, so it is pointless to try and get a spider don't there.